# searching index of first and last value greater than - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 250 files with 1000 values which makes a Gaussian curve and I need to find the first and last index of the value that is bigger than half of the maximum. I loaded files as a list of dataframes and I was able to find its maximum using `maxValues = dataframes_temp[1].max()`. I was able to find the first closest value to the HotM (half of the maximum) using `index_value_min = (dataframes_temp[1] - b[i]).apply(abs).idxmin()` but it isn't greater value than HotM, that's the first problem.

and second problem I wanted to find last index of HotM using:

```
dataframes_temp = dataframes_list[1]
dataframes_temp2 = dataframes_temp.loc[::-1]
index_value_max = (dataframes_temp2[1] - b[i]).apply(abs).idxmin()
```

but it didn't work and just only found the same value from the first part.

So how can I find indexes of first and last values bigger than HotM?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of `abs`, use `lambda x: float('inf') if x <= 0 else x` so that smaller values will not be selected.